# Is there a way of limiting the amount of orders per user in Eventbrite?

Tags: eventbrite

I need to make sure that people attending an event can't get more than one ticket per order (this is possible). However, I also need to limit the amount of possible orders to ONE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a lot of searching around and finally ended up asking EventBrite directly. Turns out this is not possible as of November 2016.